# "POST /details/3 HTTP/1.1" 405 0 (Getting 405 Error when submitting comment )

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am making one E-commerce site and trying to make the comment section below to the product detail page.
I am getting [01/Nov/2020 11:13:07] "POST /details/3 HTTP/1.1" 405 0 error in PyCharm Terminal.

Observation:

1. When I am clicking on the View Details button on the homepage site is working *(http://127.0.0.1:8000/details/3)*
   and the product detail page is getting opened.on the same page I have implemented the comment section. Please find the below details

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
# need to import Category model
from .product import Product


class Comment(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='comment',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email=models.EmailField()
    body=models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #now order we can define.

    class Meta:
        ordering=('-created',)

    #now let me take str if any person wants to display comment object.
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Commented by {} on {}'.format(self.name,self.post)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from store.models.comment import Comment


from store.models import *
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Comment
        fields=('name','email','body')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import Index,Signup,Login,logout,Cart,Check_out,Orders,Details,SearchView
from store import views
from store.middlewares.authmiddleware import authmiddleware1

urlpatterns = [
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',Index.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('signup/',Signup.as_view(),name='signup'),
    path('login', Login.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', logout, name='logout'),
    path('cart', Cart.as_view(), name='cart'),
    path('check_out', Check_out.as_view(), name='check_out'),
    path('order', authmiddleware1(Orders.as_view()), name='orders'),
    #sos here observing it is very easy and we Can monitor the things at one place.
    path('details/<int:myid>', Details.as_view(), name='details'),
    path('search/', SearchView.as_view(),name='search'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from store.forms import CommentForm
class Details(View):
    def get(self,request,myid):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=myid)
        print('Checking product value in details:',product)
        comments= product.comment.filter(active=True)
        csubmit = False

        if request.method == "POST":
            print('Checking comment post:YES')
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                print('Checking Form is Valid ba ki nahi:',form )
                new_comment = form.save(commit = False)
                new_comment.product = product
                new_comment.save()

                csubmit=True
                # return HttpResponseRedirect('/logout')
            #if not POST methos we need to display form.
        else:
            form = CommentForm()


        return render(request, 'details.html', {'product':product, 'form':form , 'comments':comments , 'csubmit':csubmit})
```

[image]

When I clicking on *submit Your Comment* button on the details page it is redirecting me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/details/3` but data is not getting saved and I am getting [01/Nov/2020 11:13:07] "POST /details/3 HTTP/1.1" 405 0 error in PyCharm Terminal.

Note: When I am adding a comment from the admin site then it is reflecting below to the product details page as shown in the image one comment was added from the admin page.

**details.html**

```html
                                <!--#######adding comment section below to post######-->
                                {% with comments.count as comment_count %}
                                <h2>{{comments_count}} Comment{{comments_count|pluralize}}</h2>
                                {%endwith%}

                                <!--#now lets display comments:)-->
                                {%if comments%}
                                {%for comment in comments%}
                                <p id='ch'> comment {{forloop.counter}} by {{comment.name}} on {{comment.created}}</p>
                                <div class="commentbody">{{comment.body|linebreaks}}</div>
                                <hr>
                                {%endfor%}

                                {%else%}
                                <p>There is no Comment Yet!!You are the first to comment on this..</p>
                                {%endif%}
                                <!--###Now if cooment is Submitted then we need to display form to end user.-->

                                {%if csubmit%}
                                <p>Hey!,Your comment has submitted successfully.To submit another comment please refresh
                                    browser! </p>
                                {%else%}
                                <!--          <p id="submit1">Please submit your comment.</p>-->
                                <form action="/details/{{product.id}}" method="post">
                                    {{form.as_p}}
                                    {%csrf_token%}
                                    <input type="submit" name="" class='btn btn-lg btn-success'
                                           value="Submit Your Comment">
                                </form>
                                {%endif%}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using View there so you have to define different function for each method. You are getting error 405 which is method not allowed because post method is not defined in your view class

```
class Details(View):
    def get(self):
        #get method request logic here
        .....

    def post(self):
        #post method request logic here
        .....

    def put(self):
        #put method request logic here
        .....

    def delete(self):
        #delete method request logic here
        .....
```

Comment: Thanks, Bhupesh!, But in views.py I'm using if request.method == "POST": and also checked by defining action in form.

Comment: No need if request method is post then it will directly run code from method post